# Facebook Syndication Error - Feed is no longer valid

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a problem with Facebook fan page RSS feed.
I need to get the feed and display latest posts on the website. It works fine if the facebook page hasn't got the location filtering switched on. As soon as location filtering is enabled, the RSS feed is unavailable and returns an error (even if accessed from allowed country).
Example http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=66157977601&format=rss20

Does anyone know if there is any workaround for that? Can I somehow pass the visitor id or a country from which the website is being accessed?

Another thing which comes to my mind is that the page is age restricted.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using the API directly (which will need you to supply an access token for a user who's able to access that content) you won't be able to access the feed of a page which is restricted.

If you want it to be available publicly with no restrictions (such as via the syndication link), you shouldn't have any restrictions set.